# undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast' when using sanitize=vptr

Tags: c++, g++, sanitizer

I build `vfptr.cpp` with `fsanitize=vptr` to an `static` file.
It has errors messages about "undefined reference to __dynamic_cast".
Both g++7.4.0 and g++11.0.0 have the problem. Is it reasonable for using sanitizer=vptr?

vptr.cpp

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() {};
};

int main() { A a; }
```

compiled option

```
g++ vptr.C -fsanitize=vptr -static
```

error message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libubsan.a(ubsan_type_hash_itanium.o): In function `isDerivedFromAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long)':
(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libubsan.a(ubsan_type_hash_itanium.o): In function `findBaseAtOffset(__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info const*, long)':
(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libubsan.a(ubsan_type_hash_itanium.o): In function `__ubsan::checkDynamicType(void*, void*, unsigned long)':
(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```